# How to get current url with its get request in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my current url:

```
http://myhost/main?my_id=1,3
```

How can I get this url in CodeIgniter, and is it included with 'my_id'?

**NOTE:**

I mean when `echo $url`, it shows like this: `http://myhost/main?my_id=1,3`

Comment: If your url helper is loaded try current_url() -- https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Thanks, bro. But do you know how to get it with its request ('my_id')?

Comment: echo $this->input->get('my_id');

Answer (score 18, accepted):

simple get like this

```
echo $this->input->get('my_id');
```

Load the URL helper To get current url

```
$currentURL = current_url(); //http://myhost/main

$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; //my_id=1,3

$fullURL = $currentURL . '?' . $params; 

echo $fullURL;   //http://myhost/main?my_id=1,3
```

Note : make sure that query string is not empty and  then concatenate .

Comment: $currentURL = current_url();
$params   = (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '');
$fullURL = $currentURL . '?' . $params;
echo $fullURL; 
======================== OR ================
echo current_url().(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '');

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgniter 4, that problem have simple solution, you just have to use these:

```
$uri = current_url(true);
echo (string) $uri; // result for your url: http://myhost/main?my_id=1,3
```

This is explained in CodeIgniter 4 documentation: [URI Strings](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#uri-strings)

Answer (score 0):

The function `current_url()` can also return an class (`URI`).

This example uses the core functionally of CI4:

```php
$uri = current_url(true);   // URI
$full_url = URI::createURIString(
    $uri->getScheme(),     // https
    $uri->getAuthority(),  // example.com
    $uri->getPath(),       // /foo/bar
    $uri->getQuery(),      // my_id=10&display=detail
); // https://example.com/foo/bar?my_id=10&display=detail
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Codeigniter 3**

create a file in `application/helpers/MY_url_helper.php`

and add the following code to it

```
<?php
function current_url($ReturnQueryParams = FALSE)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string() . (($ReturnQueryParams) ? "?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}" : ''));
}
```

and voila! just call your function `current_url(true)` will not return with server get parameters if the argument is set to true.

Answer (score -1):

simple way to get current url with its get request in CodeIgniter!

**following this code**

**Loading a Helper**

```
$this->load->helper('helper_file_name');  


$currentURL = current_url(); //http://domain/home

$params   = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; //query=what+is+php   

$url = $currentURL . '?' . $params; 

echo $url;   //http://domain/home?query=what is php
```